# Ganglia - Default graphs not showing up

Tags: rrd, ganglia

I am using Ganglia UI to monitor a bunch of distributed clusters. All the graphs are working except the default graphs (load, memory, cpu and network). Ganglia gmond is not storing those information in rrd. This is the error I am getting while starting the gmond service.
 `Cannot load /location/ganglia-install/lib64/ganglia/modcpu.so metric module: location/ganglia-install/lib64/ganglia/modcpu.so: undefined symbol: timediff`

Comment: I have installed ganglia, rrd tool and its dependencies without root access. Have I missed anything while configuring Ganglai?